# C# AutoCAD Get Block and Dynamic Block with Count

Tags: c#, autocad

Im trying to get all Block and Dynamic Blocks from my Drawing and the actual Count. But im having a weird issue where the Count of each block is 1 more than Expected. To get the count of the normal BlockReferences im counting the Duplicates. But for the dynamic Blocks im getting the actual count
with var blockCount= anonymousBtr.GetBlockReferenceIds(true, true).Count;
 
What im trying for Normal Blocks:

```
 public static void GetShelfBlock() {
            var acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            var acDb = acDoc.Database;
            var dataCollection = new List<DataModel>();

            using (var tr = acDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {

                try {
                    var entClass = RXObject.GetClass(typeof(Entity));
                    var modelSpaceId = SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(acDb);
                    var modelSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(modelSpaceId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                    foreach (var id in modelSpace) {
                        if (!id.ObjectClass.IsDerivedFrom(entClass)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        var ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                        if (!ent.GetType().ToString().Contains(typeof(BlockReference).Name)) {
                continue;
                        }

                        var reference = ent as BlockReference;
                        if (reference == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        var blockReference = reference;
                        if (CheckPattern(blockReference.Name)) {
                            dataCollection.Add(PrepareShelfObject(blockReference));
                        }
                    }
                    tr.Commit();
                    tr.Dispose();

                    dataCollection.AddRange(GetDynamicBlocks(SearchPatterns));
                    if (dataCollection.Count > 0) {
                        Serialize(dataCollection, DataType.Regale);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    acDoc.Editor.WriteMessage(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

what im trying for Dynamic Blocks where im getting the count with var blockCount= `anonymousBtr.GetBlockReferenceIds(true, true).Count;`

```
public static List<DataModel> GetDynamicBlocks() {
            var db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
            var dynamicBlockList = new List<DataModel>();
            var tempList = new List<object>();
            using (var trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {
                var bt = (BlockTable)trans.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);

                foreach (var btrId in bt) {

                    var btr = (BlockTableRecord)trans.GetObject(btrId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    if (!btr.IsDynamicBlock) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var anonymousIds = btr.GetAnonymousBlockIds();
                    var dynBlockRefs = new ObjectIdCollection();

                    foreach (ObjectId anonymousBtrId in anonymousIds) {
                        var anonymousBtr = (BlockTableRecord)trans.GetObject(anonymousBtrId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                        var blockRefIds = anonymousBtr.GetBlockReferenceIds(true, true);
                        foreach (ObjectId id in blockRefIds) {
                            dynBlockRefs.Add(id);
                        }
                    }

                    if (searchPattern.Any(btr.Name.StartsWith)) {
                        dynamicBlockList.Add(PrepareDynObject(btr));
                    }
                }
                trans.Commit();
                trans.Dispose();
            }
            return dynamicBlockList;
        }
```

Is there a way to Get all the blocks and there Count ?? Im before giving up i tried everything for 3 days now .... Maybe somebody can help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using Linq.

```
    public void ListBlocks()
    {
        var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var db = doc.Database;
        var ed = doc.Editor;

        using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
        {
            var modelSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
                SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db), OpenMode.ForRead);

            var brclass = RXObject.GetClass(typeof(BlockReference));

            var blocks = modelSpace
                .Cast<ObjectId>()
                .Where(id => id.ObjectClass == brclass)
                .Select(id => (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead))
                .GroupBy(br => ((BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
                    br.DynamicBlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead)).Name);

            foreach (var group in blocks)
            {
                ed.WriteMessage($"\n{group.Key}: {group.Count()}");
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
    }
```